# Getting "access denied" error when query a shared dataset in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Title says it all. I can query using the browser query tool but same query via the API returns Access Denied. Is it possible to query shared datasets via the API?

Answer (score 2):

Is the API interaction that doesn't work via a service account?  A service account is its own security principal, so it may be that it needs to be explicitly included in the relevant project/dataset permissions.

You can also use the [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/bigquery/v2/) to directly exercise the BigQuery API using your own logged in credentials.

Comment: Not a service account - just a regular server flow oauth.

Comment: I tested with the API Explorer and have the same result - I cannot see shared datasets.

Comment: Can you post the API request/response?  The web UI uses the API over javascript, so there's not a fundamental difference in how it works.